# Ocaml and Algorithmic Trading

Tags: ocaml, algorithmic-trading, quantitative-finance

I'm completely new to the Algorithmic Trading domain. I've just completed a course that was Ocaml based, and read about Jane Street. Obviously they are a huge company with a large amount of resources, but is it feasible to use Ocaml for small time algorithmic trading?

I know that probably seems like a stupid question, but (from what i've found) there aren't any trading APIs for Ocaml. This would mean one would have to written from scratch correct?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated guys, like I said I am a complete noob to this domain.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I've recently noticed this package in Opam that could provide a starting point for a trading API:
"[IBX](https://bitbucket.org/ogu/ibx) is a pure OCaml implementation of the Interactive Brokers Trader Workstation API (TWS API) built on top of Jane Street's Core and Async library."

As for open source trading algorithms in general this project started recently:
http://scarcecapital.com/hft/

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is probably too open-ended for the Stack Overflow environment to be useful to you. Stack Overflow is for when you have a specific problem you're trying to solve.

But being opinionated, I can't help but say that OCaml might be pretty good for algorithmic trading. The strong typing system and immutable data tend to help avoid errors while allowing you to code quickly. This, at least, is what I've found. But you'd need to plug OCaml in to your data sources and your trade execution channel, which would be extra work. Knowing nothing about this area, I don't know if there are libraries for other languages.

Most likely the folks who are actually doing this have an incentive to keep their secrets to themselves. But that would be true regardless of the language.

Comment: I think Ocaml would be great for this as well. I love the language, unfortunately I'm in the minority haha. You are probably right about it being to open ended. However, any guidance would be great. Thanks for the input!